# Scala less typing with arguments of same type

Tags: scala

In GoLang, if a function accepts several arguments of the same type you can type it as:

```
add := func(x, y int) int {
  return x + y
}
```

In which both `x` and `y` are of type `int`.

But I am not able to find out whether such a shorthand notation exists for scala. I've tried following, to no avail.

```
> def add(x, y: Int): Int = { x + y} 

error: ':' expected but ',' found.
```

For a simple case like, it's not much of a burden. But for some case classes I've come up with, this looks very verbose, conflicting with scala's stance on verbosity.

Is there a such scala feature or syntactic sugar, if there is how can I use it?

Comment: No, no such notation in scala. But I sometimes use shorter type aliases for Int, String, etc as `type I = Int` to shorten long signatures, for example when defining many case classes for JSON or database lib.

Comment: I think such notation would have a lot of problems in Scala, especially with lambda's, where you do not always have to specify the type of the variable due to type inference.

Comment: Like @dmitry has already mentioned, theris no such feature. A workaround could be a List[Int] to pass around data. But again, it has huge potential for abuse.

Comment: @dmitry Well I take that as an answer. Good point on type aliasing, never thought about that.

Comment: @Archeg Why would it? You mean, for example, type of one argument is inferred and the other is not, thus causing ambiguity? Is that possible?

Comment: @ChetanBhasin A list would imply indefinite amount of arguments with no name, I would like to have definite amount of arguments with names.

Comment: @MehmetM.Inanc I think this could be solved in compiler, but it just isn't. Not because there are some fundamental difficulty to parse this unambiguously, but people never thought it is necessary. Though it is a nice feature of Go, but I still can live without it happily :)

Comment: @MehmetM.Inanc Right now you can specify one argument type explicitly, and omit the other one, even though both are inferenced. But still this would mean that you have the same syntax for both type inference and this feature. To be honest, scala already has some different features that uses the same syntax, such as `_` that is used everywhere and I see people often confuses them. It just always feels bad, and I don't think the intention is to increase such things. But this is my personal feeling, Martin and others could have it different, but I think it is unlikely. It is not useful enough

Comment: @dmitry Yes, it is not much of a deal but my `case class`es with 10 string arguments would look much nicer and cleaner :). Thanks. If you could post it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, scala has no this exact feature.

Indeed, sometimes function/class signatures turn out to be very long, especially when defining something like case classes for spray.json or for slick.

I found a tolerable hint using `type` aliases for frequently used types in this case.

```
object TypeShortcuts {
  type I = Int
  type L = Long
  type S = String
  type D = Double
  type B = Boolean
  type O[T] = Option[T]
}

import TypeShortcuts._
```

And then this nasty long declaration:

```
case class Country(id: Int, currencyId: Option[Int], latin2: String, latin3: String, digital: String, names: Names, phoneCode: String)
```

I can rewrite into more bearable (and importantly - concise):

```
case class Country(id: I, currencyId: O[I], latin2: S, latin3: S, digital: S, names: Names, phoneCode: S)
```

This was especially handy in some corner case with slick, like :), just imagine the horror of full name version:

```
def applyOpt(t: (O[I], O[I], O[I], O[S], O[S], O[S], O[S], O[S], O[S], O[S], O[S], O[S], O[S], O[S], O[S], O[S])): O[BankInfo]
```

Comment: If you feel you need this, then it's probably a sign that you are giving your classes or methods too many parameters...

Comment: @Jesper I don't always choose this by myself, but it may be a requirement dictated by some external agents. Just a simple example: pre-existing database.

Comment: @Jesper On a similar note, working with extracted and transformed data, csv or whatever, naturally requires this sort of stuff. Even if the original data is well structured and normalized, transformations may result in very dimensional datasets. Think of joins, or more specifically, denormalized data.

Answer (score 4):

In Scala, suffix the type with `*` to denote a sequence of values of such type, for instance

```
def add(x: Int*): Int = x.sum
add: (x: Int*)Int
```

and so

```
scala> add(1,2,3)
res0: Int = 6
```

Now `x: Int*` is a sequence of `Int` values, consider

```
def addMeta(x: Int*): Int = x.length
addMeta: (x: Int*)Int

scala> addMeta(0,1,2,3)
res1: Int = 4
```

Comment: Good point and a definitely very useful struct, but please see my comment to @ChetanBasin.